# 기는 하다 grammar used in a question

Tags: grammar, meaning

This 살긴 살아요 is from grammar structure 기는 하다 (acknowledging something in the first clause before contrasting it in the second) but I've ever seen it used in a question like that, so I can't quite get the feeling. 
Can anyone explain it?

> 근데 이 근처에 다른 애들도 살긴 살아요?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-기는 하다 is used to support the positive statement in the first clause but it describes the opposite statement in the second clause.

이 셔츠는 예쁘기는 하지만 비싸요.
This shirt is pretty but expensive.

저는 힘들기는 하지만 기분은 좋아요.
I am tired but feel good.

But if you use -기는 하다 in the question, it conveys the feeling of doubt.

이런 낡은 집에 사람이 살긴 살아? 
Are you sure that anyone is really living in such an old house?

너가 진짜 피아노를 칠 수 있긴 있어? 
Are you really able to play the piano?

그 남자가 정말 오긴 오는 거야? 
Is the man really coming for sure?